# A divisor which is local complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Here Hartshorne's  definition of a closed subscheme of a variety which is local complete intersection:

[image]

Now suppose that $D$ is an *effective*  divisor (Weil or Cartier) on $X$. My question is the following:

> 1) What is the meaning to say "$D$ is local complete intersection"? I suppose that one wants to say  that " **the support of** $D$ is local complete intersection".
>
> 2) Once that the previous point is clarified I'd like to know under which conditions on $D$ we can conclude that it is local
>   complete intersection.

Comment: Any divisor on a smooth variety is a local complete intersection.

Comment: May I ask why is this true?

Comment: Any divisor on a smooth variety is in fact a Cartier divisor, which makes it trivially a local complete intersection of just itself.